# Understanding Properties of Measure

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand measure and was thinking about the following:
 If X and Y are open subsets of R such that $X\subset Y$ but X and Y are not equal, then $m(X)<m(Y)$. Is this statement true? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you remove one point from $Y$?

Comment: If you remove a point from Y there measures are equal?

Comment: Yes, if $X=Y\setminus \{c\}$ for some $c\in Y$, then $m(X)=m(Y)$ which contradicts your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Take $Y = (0,2)$ and $X = (0,1)\cup(1,2)$. Then $X \subset Y$ but $m(X) = m(Y) = 2$. That is because the difference between $X$ and $Y$ is only one point, namely $\{1\}$, which has measure zero.